# Segmentation fault using SSE _mm_shuffle_ps

Tags: c++, sse

I'm using SSE instruction on my program to increase it performances but it often crashes on a call to `_mm_shuffle_ps`.

I know that most probably it is due to alignment that needs to be at 16 byte, but I can't really get around this issue.

This is the code I use (my program is compiled at 32bit with VisualStudio 2017):

```
#define SHUFFLEMASK(A0,A1,B2,B3) ( (A0) | ((A1)<<2) | ((B2)<<4) | ((B3)<<6) )

inline __m128 RotateVector(const __m128& quaternion, const __m128& vector)
{
    const uint32 shuffleMask = SHUFFLEMASK(3, 3, 3, 3);

    // THE NEXT LINE IS THE ONE CRASHING
    const __m128 qw = _mm_shuffle_ps(quaternion, quaternion, shuffleMask);

    // The rest isn't useful since it crashes before even getting there
    ...
}

inline __m128 MakeVectorRegister(float X, float Y, float Z, float W)
{
    return _mm_setr_ps(X, Y, Z, W);
}

class Vertex
{
public:
    union
    {
        float vec[3];
        struct
        {
            float x, y, z;
        };
    };

    // Rest of class (only methods, no other attributes)
    ...
};

__declspec(align(16)) class X
{
    ...

    __m128 _scale;
    __m128 _rotation;

    ...

    Vertex TransformVector(const Vertex& vector) const
    {
        float __declspec(align(16)) vectorData[3];
        memcpy(vectorData, &vector.x, sizeof(float) * 3);

        // The next line was originally this: const __m128 inputVectorW0 = MakeVectorRegister(((const float*)(&vector.x))[0], ((const float*)(&vector.x))[1], ((const float*)(&vector.x))[2], 0.0f)
        const __m128 inputVectorW0 = MakeVectorRegister(((const float*)(vectorData))[0], ((const float*)(vectorData))[1], ((const float*)(vectorData))[2], 0.0f)

        const __m128 scaledVec = _mm_mul_ps(_scale, inputVectorW0);
        const __m128 rotatedVec = RotateVector(_rotation, scaledVec);

        // The rest isn't useful since it crashes before
        ...
    }
}

// Example of usage
int main(...)
{
    Vertex v;
    X x;

    // This crashes calling _mm_shuffle_ps inside RotateVector
    Vertex result = x.TransformVector(v);
}
```

Comment: Your given code does not crash on my system (Linux). You need to align your memory when using `mm_store_ps` or `mm_load_ps` but not when setting the four values individually as you do by using `mm_setr_ps`

Comment: Yeah, in fact doing some other tests I found out that the problem is with the `_rotation` attribute of the class which seems unaligned...but it is a `__m128` which it should be aligned by default...

Comment: The strange thing is that it doesn't crash every time but every once in a while it starts crashing for some time, then it works again, then it crashes. And all the variables are initialized...strange behaviour

Comment: Exactly, according to MSDN `Variables of type _m128 are automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries.`

Comment: Doing this test inside the `RotateVector` function `(intptr_t)(&quaternion) & 15` to see the alignment, turn out it is `8` when a crash occurs, and `0` when there isn't a crash

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but just FYI `SHUFFLEMASK` already exists as [`_MM_SHUFFLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d3eabky(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @zeb: are you casting some arbitrary data to `__m128` at some point prior to your call to `RotateVector` ? I think we need to see the code that calls `RotateVector` to see how the `quaternion` parameter is being derived.

Comment: @PaulR: no, all the SSE data is set through SSE instructions, no casts involved (BTW, thanks for `_MM_SHUFFLE`)

Comment: I don't think this acctually matters, but could it be the position where I declared the `_scale` and `_rotation` attributes inside the class? BTW, the class itself is aligned to 16 bytes (I updated the code inside the question)

Comment: How are you instantiating your class ? (Note that `__declspec(align(16))` doesn't have any effect if you're using e.g. `new`.)

Comment: The place where the class is instantiated in my actual program is actually as an attribute of another class which, to be fair, is instantiated whit a new a I just realized that I didn't override the default `new` operator for that class. Could be it maybe?, I'm trying as of now.

Comment: Seems like that was the actual problem. I'll keep it checked to see how it behaves, but overriding the `new` operator of the class hosting the `X` class seems to work fine

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it - you might want to post the above comments as an answer, although I think this may well be a duplicate of previous similar questions.

Comment: Maybe it is too soon to say the I've fixed it but if that's the case you're right, in the end is Always the missing `new` operator. We'll see, maybe just to clarify what the problem was.

Comment: Since you're on 32-bit Windows, the default allocator only returns 8-byte aligned memory.  64-bit Windows and Linux give you 16-byte aligned memory from `new`, IIRC.  You could use a debugger to confirm that your faults are happening with a misaligned address to an aligned-load instruction (or an SSE ALU instruction with a memory operand).

Comment: BTW, that `memcpy` is nasty, and might well not optimize away especially as an input to `_mm_set`.  I'd highly recommend just doing a `_mm_loadu_ps` from the original data (as long as it can't be right at the end of a page before an unmapped page).  If you need to zero the high element, use `_mm_and_ps` with a constant.  Ideally you would have a whole vector of `x` and a whole vector of `y`, etc. instead of putting multiple components of the same 3D geometry vector into one SIMD register.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info

Comment: See also https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ for why using SIMD this way is a pitfall.

Comment: @PeterCordes : you're right about that `memcpy`, I know that isn't a thing to so. That was just a test of mine to see if the problem was the vector data. Originally I was doing a __mm_load_ps from my vector without `memcpy`